# How to get browser console error messages using Selenium WebDriver + NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium Webdriver for Javascript/NodeJS, how can I get the `console.log` and `console.error` of the browser?

I am using headless browser engines

```js
const { Builder, By, until } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox')

// get selectedBrowser and url from CLI options
let selectedBrowser, url

(async ()=> {
  let driver
  const screen = { width: 1920, height: 1080 }
  switch (selectedBrowser) {
    case 'firefox':
      driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .setFirefoxOptions(new firefox.Options().headless().windowSize(screen))
        .build()
      break
    case 'chrome':
      driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless().windowSize(screen))
        .build()
      break
    default:
      throw Error('Wrong browser: ' + frontendTest)
  }

  await driver.get(url)

  // etc.
})()
```

Comment: Hier ist the solution for c#: [How to get browser console error messages using Selenium WebDriver + C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351421/how-to-get-browser-console-error-messages-using-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp/70351422#70351422)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the official [selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/logging.html), you must:

first, set the logging preferences

```
var prefs = new logging.Preferences();
prefs.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.DEBUG);

var caps = Capabilities.chrome();
caps.setLoggingPrefs(prefs);
```

and then retrieve the logs

```
driver.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER)
     .then(function(entries) {
        entries.forEach(function(entry) {
          console.log('[%s] %s', entry.level.name, entry.message);
        });
     });
```

Comment: thanks, I will test and as soon as it works, I set your answer as correct answer, thanks again

Comment: how do you import "logging"?